# Win 8.1 + Ubuntu, 256GB SSD, partitioning scheme

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

I would like to install Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu(both x64) on a one 256 GB SSD.
I need 3 partitions, 2 for systems and 1 shared(NTFS?) for data accessible by both OSes. '/root' and '/home' will be on same Ubuntu's partition, I'd like to move swap into RAM(12GB) with '[zram](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/increased-performance-in-linux-with.html)'.

I'd like to have the largest possible 'data' partition but wouldn't want to run out of space on the system ones.

Basic apps installed on a system partition:

- Windows: NetBeans, Java (JDK) + optinally Eclipse, MS Office, Photoshop.
- Ubuntu: R Studio, NetBeans.

1) What would be the optimal partitioning scheme?

I was thinking about:

- Ubuntu 60 GB Ext4
- Win8 90 GB NTFS
- Data ~100GB NTFS

2) Is removing swap in my configuration a good idea?

Thanks :)

Comment: You don't need to allocate that size to Ubuntu. Less than 30 GB or even less than that would be enough to create a Ubuntu partition. But removing swap partition is actually not a good idea. For most cases, it should be needed.

Comment: I am trying to avoid creating swap on SSD as it may not be good for the drive. I may try to use zram instead.

Comment: @Alan you can instead create a swapfile in your partition. In that way, you do not need a separate partition and you have a swap space, which is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would:

- 24 GB Ubuntu System + applications: EXT4,
- 64 GB Windows System+Applications: NTFS
- 150 GB /home from Ubuntu and /users from Windows: NTFS

I've run like this for 6 months before deleting Windows altogether and converting NTFS to EXT4 after another couple of months.

If you have 12GB of RAM, [use this formula](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594054/how-much-swap-should-i-take-for-1-128gb-ram-on-14-04) to calculate your swap file needs.

Comment: Thanks for advice, I'll try that out. Maybe I'll make Linux partition a bit larger and install JDK there, while keeping Windows only for Office work and Photoshop.

Comment: My Linux partition has only 10GB *allocated* (out of 64GB).  I wouldn't make it bigger then 24 GB... (unless you need a lot of temp file space to load huge torrents!)