# Installing Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I have two question :
First, if i want to install windows and Ubuntu on UEFI, the installation images should be boot into USB as GPT or MBR?(or i must use another method)

Second, I have an 128 GB of SSD.If I want to make both Ubuntu and Windows to Start fast, which partition I should have create In SSD? Or what Is the best Partitioning especially to start both OS fast?

Thank you In advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Win 8.1 + Ubuntu, 256GB SSD, partitioning scheme](https://askubuntu.com/questions/567668/win-8-1-ubuntu-256gb-ssd-partitioning-scheme)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use GPT over MBR because as MBR was invented back in 1983, so it is old and has several limitations this is where GPT has advantage over MBR.

Limitations of MBR:

- It doesn't work on the disk size over 2TB
- It only supports up to 4 only 4 primary partitions
- Boot data is stored in a single place if it is overwritten or deleted that means error in starting the OS

Pros of GPT:

- It supports disk size greater than 2TB
- It also gives you support for making numerous partial but the number varies with each OS. ex: It supports up to 128 partitions for Windows
- It stores multiple copies of boot data across disk is data is corrupted anyhow it recovers it easily

In short, GPT is modern new and overcome the limitations of MBR.

As for as the second question is considered if you are not going to install heavy software on windows then you can partition SSD in 2 parts but I would not recommend it.

It better to figure out which OS you use most and install it on SSD and the other on HDD, it's totally up to you.